# Delete a specific file and reupload to S3 bucket from Github using Github actions

Tags: github-actions

I am having files in GitHub and same set of files in S3 bucket. If i make changes to a file in github, s3 bucket need to delete a specific changed file and reupload the same file to s3. Is that possible using GitHub actions?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it's possible. One way to achieve that will be to use existing open-source actions from GitHub Marketplace, for example:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/aws-s3-github-action

Comment: I already tried this. This will only overwrite the files. But i want to delete and upload new files.

Comment: Use different commands then - you have a "command" parameter which allows you to delete stuff.